# Spring MVC/JSP handle huge forms

Tags: forms, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm displaying a couple instances of a class on the front end, where the user can change every attribute of the object, this can add up to 1000 `<select>`s in a single form.

**Class**

```
@Entity
public class Entity extends ModelBase{
    @OneToOne
    private AnotherEntity entityInstance;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private AEnum sessionOne = AEnum.None;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private AEnum sessionTwo = AEnum.None;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private AEnum sessionThree = AEnum.None;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private AEnum sessionFour = AEnum.None;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private AEnum sessionFive = AEnum.None;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private AEnum sessionSix = AEnum.None;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private AEnum sessionSeven = AEnum.None;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private AEnum sessionEight = AEnum.None;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private AEnum sessionNine = AEnum.None;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private AEnum sessionTen = AEnum.None;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private AEnum sessionEleven = AEnum.None;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private AEnum sessionTwelve = AEnum.None;

        ...
}
```

**JSP File**

```
<form>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><select for sessionOne></td>
      <td><select for sessionTwo></td>
      <td><select for sessionThree></td>
      <td><select for sessionFour></td>
      <td><select for sessionFive></td>
      <td><select for sessionSix></td>
      <td><select for sessionSeven></td>
      <td><select for sessionEight></td>
      <td><select for sessionNine></td>
      <td><select for sessionTen></td>
      <td><select for sessionEleven></td>
      <td><select for sessionTwelve></td>
    </tr>
    ...
  </table>
  <button type="submit">
</form>
```

What's the best way to submit the form? Running threw every select by name seems not to be the best way.

Comment: It is a question about page design and user experience, isn't it? Maybe better way is to make object creation with multipage forms?

Comment: Maybe I should've said it in the OP, but selects will only be the solution, if javascript is disabled. With enabled Javascript the user experience will be a lot better, it'll be possible to set as many fields as the user likes at once. I should also mention that the number of fields will be around 50-150 for the majority of users, but in extreme cases it can go up to 1000. I agree it seems like a really bad design, but I think it's the best way to realize it, especially keeping the js experience in mind.

Comment: Have you tried spring "form" taglib? If no I can post an answer with example

Comment: If you think the spring form tag makes it easier to handle the amount of data on the backend, please post an example. Maybe it's possible to bind one table row to an object. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to use spring "form" taglib. You can create special class that encapsulate all fields and pass it to model in your "GET" method (that displays page). Assume that name of passed object is "entity". Also you have to pass list of all enum values to your model. (See example here: [spring-form:options tag with enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15073830/spring-formoptions-tag-with-enum)). Jsp will look like this:

```
<form:form commandName="entity" action="/action" method="POST">
    <form:select path="sessionOne">
        <form:options items="${availableOptions}" />
    </form:select>
    <form:select path="sessionTwo">
        <form:options items="${availableOptions}" />
    </form:select>
    <!-- and so on -->
</form:>
```

Controller code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/action", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String handleHugeForm(@ModelAttribute Entity entity) {
    // do what you want
}
```

Spring "form" taglib tutorial: http://www.dzone.com/tutorials/java/spring/spring-form-tags-1.html